# STS (Spring Tools Suite) writes STS.ini any time I get updated, merging with my own configuration

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

To improve my STS performance I've added some parameters to STS.ini. But every time I update the tool, it puts its own configuration at the beginning of STS.ini file, relegating my configuration to the end, sometimes duplicating several parameters.

Is there another way to avoid this?

Now, everytime I update the tool I need to backup the file and check the parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to launch Eclipse and STS from the command line.  I create a bunch of shell scripts, one for each variant of Eclipse/STS that I run.  This ensures that every launch has precisely the arguments that I need.

For example, I have a bunch of scripts like this:

```
[21:09] ~/Eclipse
$ more eclipse_42.sh
Installations/Eclipse4.2.M6/Eclipse -data \
    "/users/Andrew/Eclipse/Workspaces/workspace_42" \
    -vmargs -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

I like running from a terminal so that you can see what gets sent to sysout.  And this could also be launched from a Finder window.

I run on Mac, but you could do something similar on Linux or Windows.

Comment: This answer doesn't resolve my issue, but it's very interesting and I'll give it a try, so upvote for you!

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of another possible answer.  I haven't tried this, but it could work.

Instead of doing "Check for updates", go to the install manager Help -> Install new software...

With the STS update site, select all the components that you want updated (**except** SpringSource Tool suite (required) and SpringSource Tool Suite Package (if you see it)).

I think it is these two components that alter the STS.ini.  The only thing that I am not sure of is if it is at all possible to update individual components without updating that package.